# Promise that just returns?

Tags: typescript, promise

I noticed the following in the code base I'm currently working with and am not sure what the point of it is:

`public spinnerPromise: Promise<void> = new Promise<void>(() => { return; });`

Is there a reason to have an empty Promise?  This reminds me of doing a 
`setTimeOut(fn, 0)` and I'm wondering if it has a similar effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

As @Bergi pointed out, the given promise never fulfills as no one calls resolve. So the promise in question will never call anybody waiting for the result.

A promise equivalent to a `setTimeOut(fn, 0)` would be:

```
var spinnerPromise: Promise<void> = new Promise<void>(resolve => resolve());
```

**Original**

Yes the effect is similar. The `Promise` [specification](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34) mandates that even if the `Promise` is in the fulfilled state, any handler will not be called right when the handler is registered. It will get called only when the current call is done executing.

```
spinnerPromise.then (()=> { /* Code called later */ });
// Code called after call to then
```

Comment: I don't mind being downvoted, but could the downvoter provide a reason ? If the answer is wrong I want to know.

Comment: The promise that the OP has does never get into the fulfilled state.

Comment: @Bergi yes you are right, my bad, I missed that, I was thinking of a promise that looks like this `new Promise<void>(r => r())`

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reason to have an empty Promise?

I can't think of many. One use case would be as a value that you can pass to `Promise.race` and expect it to always take the other choice.

Have a look at [Are JavaScript forever-pending promises bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38286358/1048572) and [Is it safe to not resolve or reject a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23037183/1048572).

> This reminds me of doing a `setTimeOut(fn, 0)` and I'm wondering if it has a similar effect.

No, not at all. `setTimeout` will eventually call the callback, but `new Promise(() => {}).then(…)` never will. It's more akin to passing `Infinity` to `setTimeout` (which [doesn't really work in reality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3468607/1048572)).

You might be thinking of `Promise.resolve().then(…)` or `new Promise(r => r()).then(…)`, which will call the callback function immediately but asynchronously.