# Resolving promises without passing through variables

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, chaining

I am learning about using promises and am trying to use functional programming to achieve code modularity. My issue is that as I progress through the `then()` chain that I am passing parameters through intermediary `then()` calls for later functions to use.

This feels unnecessary and I think I am missing the forest for the trees.

```
function getSession(user, pass) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do something with user and pass
        resolve(session)
    })
}


function getAccount(session) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do something with session - pass through session
        resolve([session, account])
    })
}

function doThing(session, account) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do something with account - pass through session
        resolve([session, thing])
    })
}

function doOtherThing(session, thing) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do something with session and thing
        resolve(otherThing)
    })
}

let example = getSession(user, pass).then(getAccount).then(doThing).then(doOtherThing)
```

So for example, `doThing()` is passed `session` and `account` but only does something to `account`. However, since `doOtherThing()` requires `session`, I pass through the session instance so it can be used by that function.

So to eliminate passing through these extra variables I want to do *something like*

```
function getAccount(session) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do something with session
        resolve(account)
    })
}

function doThing(account) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do something with account
        resolve(thing)
    })
}

let session = getSession(user, pass)
let thing = getSession(user, pass).then(getAccount).then(doThing)
let example = doOtherThing(session, thing)
```

As you can see, most of these functions return a promise so I can improve code modularity by chaining elsewhere. As such the `session` and `thing` variables are assigned promises.

However in this case, I just want to resolve both promises in `session` and `thing` to then be used in `doOtherThing(session, thing)`

I tried something like

```
let session = getSession(user, pass).resolve()
let thing = getSession(user, pass).then(getAccount).then(doThing).resolve()
```

and

```
let example = doOtherThing(session.resolve(), thing.resolve())
```

but I get `resolve is not a function` as an error.

Also I know

```
let session = getSession(user, pass)
let thing = getSession(user, pass).then(getAccount).doThing(account)
let example = doOtherThing(session, thing)
```

doesn't make sense since the promises in both variables need to be resolved before passing them to `doOtherThing()` but I am drawing a blank as to how to do this - so this is more pseudo code showing that I don't want to pass through session

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008607/resolving-a-promise-without-calling-the-then) but I don't think I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: You may be interested in this: [How to chain promise and share prior results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863).

Comment: this could be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain

Comment: If you `example` is a function that takes `[user,pass]` and returns `otherThing` then you can hard code the functions that convert `[user,pass] => session => thing => [session,thing] => otherThing` and use closure but what if the functions themselves are passed or defined as an array of functions? You can map over them and use a utility called thread, an example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677470/1641941)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790818/817379), it seems the cleanest and most readable way to do this is using `async`

```
function getAccount(session) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do something with session
        resolve(account)
    })
}

function doThing(account) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // do something with account
        resolve(thing)
    })
}

const main = async () => {
    let session = await getSession(user, pass)
    let account = await getAccount(session)
    let thing = await doThing(account)
    let otherThing = await doOtherThing(session, account)

    return(otherthing)
}

let otherThingResult = main()
```

This allows the promises to be executed in a familiar synchronous code style and gives a number of advantages;

1. Variables do not need to be passed through 'chained promises'
   meaning the results from these resolved promises can be single
   variables rather than an array containing the desired variable and
   the passed through variables
2. Which in turn allows 'chained' promise function parameters to accept 
   individual variables rather than using destructuring of arrays increasing 
   reusability of code
3. The use of `Promise.all()` in other areas of code now hints more at its 
   original functionality of executing an array of unrelated promises 
   asynchronously
4. Code indentation remains low and readability greatly improves

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out a way - not sure if it is the cleanest, but it removes passing through variables

```
let session = getSession(user, pass)
let thing = session.then(getAccount).doThing(account)

Promise.all([session, thing])
    .then((promises => { 
        [session, thing] = promises

        return doOtherThing(session, thing) 
    }))
    .then(otherThing => { console.log(otherThing) })
```

Comment: this line may give you error in strict mode as undeclared var `[session, thing] = promises`

Answer (score 0):

Does this look cleaner?

```
let session = getSession(user, pass)
let thing = session.then(getAccount).doThing(account)

Promise.all([
  session,
  thing
]).then(data => {
  return doOtherThing(...data)
}).then(anyOtherThing => {
  console.log(anyOtherThing)
}).catch(console.log);
```