# Are JavaScript forever-pending promises bad?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Say I have a promise called `myProm`, and say I have success and error handlers called `onSuccess` and `onError`.

Whenever my promise takes longer than 10 seconds to complete, I want a function called `timeoutHandler` to be executed, but if that happens, neither `onSuccess` nor `onError` should be executed. (Similarly, if either `onSuccess` or `onError` runs, I don't want my `timeoutHandler` to be executed.)

I've come up with the following snippet for this.

```
new Promise((suc, err) => {
    let outOfTime = false;
    const timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
        outOfTime = true;
        timeoutHandler();
    }, 10000);
    myProm.then(
        (...args) => {
            if (!outOfTime) {
                window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                suc(...args);
            }
        },
        (...args) => {
            if (!outOfTime) {
                window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                err(...args);
            }
        }
    );
}).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

However, in case of a timeout, my newly defined promise will be forever-pending. Could this have any negative side effects? For example, the runtime not being able to clean up the Promise object because it's still pending (or something along those lines).

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068467/do-never-resolved-promises-cause-memory-leak

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be no side effect. It would be a browser bug if a non-referenced `Promise` in whatever state is keeping resources.

Just make sure you don't keep any reference to the `Promise` object and you'll be fine.

Beware that certain APIs such as `setTimeout` will keep a reference to the closure up to the timeout value. This means that if you have a long timeout, like the 10s one, you should clear it as soon as you don't need it anymore. Otherwise your code can call thousands of `setTimeout` within 10s, and each of them will keep a reference to the closure, which in your case will reference the `Promise`.

Comment: But notice that `suc` and `err` do keep the promise alive as well, and `myProm` does keep references to them, so this leads all the way down the rabbit hole…

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Promise.race()`, set `timeoutHandler` as a function which returns a rejected a `Promise` in ten seconds, else `onSuccess` should be called at fulfilled `Promise` of `myProm`

```js
function myProm() {
  return new Promise((success, err) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      success("myProm")
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 11000))
  })
}

function timeoutHandler() {
  return new Promise((_, timeout) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      timeout(new Error("timeoutHandler"));
    }, 10000)
  })
}

function onSuccess(data) {
  console.log("success", data)
}

function onError(err) {
  console.log("err:", err)
}

function onTimeout(e) {
  if (e.message && e.message === "timeoutHandler") {
    console.log(e.message + " handled");
  }
  else { 
    onError(e)
  }
}

Promise.race([myProm(), timeoutHandler()])
.then(onSuccess, onTimeout);
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9UD5syOEOc1oQGdRTRRm?p=preview

Comment: Using `.catch()` chained to `timeoutHandler()`, `throw`, `Boolean` flag, `if` condition to determine whether or not to do stuff within `if` statement at `onError` http://plnkr.co/edit/SmkHN6EPjSQCrnROYWZv?p=preview

Comment: Can you please update the code in your answer so that there are three functions `timeoutHandler, `onSuccess` and `onError` of which exactly one is executed, like the OP requested?

Comment: @Bergi See updated post. Not clear from Question or your comment whether error should be propagated to downstream chained `.then()`, `.catch()` or not?

Comment: You're still not calling a `onTimeout`, but if you did replace the `null` with it then it would look good